# Error in Microsoft power-automate flow when getting row from spreadsheet updated by form

Tags: office-365, power-automate

I am trying to automate the following process

> There is a form "Behaviour Breach Report". This updates at table "Behave" in a spreadsheet "Behaviour Incident" (which is stored on OneDrive)
>
> When a new response is made to the form, I want to automatically check if the field "Upper School Year Group" of the response has the value "Class 9", and if so, send an email.

So I have the following:

[image]

When I test this flow, the "Get a row" fails with this error message

```
No row was found with Id '10'.
clientRequestId: 4034a68e-29a4-4b54-893f-bdcc9509bc03
serviceRequestId: 6a0b0afd-46dc-4e5a-b8ab-bb5ee17861b2;23c4a7dc-a0c0-4950-b1b8-56dbe17c7c97;c4a26daa-34c7-4ca5-9182-e50d3634b5ba
```

However looking at the spreadsheet, a row with ID 10 is present and contains the information that I entered into the form.

What is happening here?  Is the row in the linked spreadsheet not updated until after the flow runs?  Is the logic  of Table, Key Column and Key Value not correct.

I would expect this flow to return the values in the row of the table with ID = 10 and not give an error.

I have tried with a fixed value of '1' for the Key Value, and with this fixed value, the flow works, and continues to the next stage (which sends the email).

Is the spreadsheet not updated quickly enough, and so when the flow runs, the new row hasn't yet been added?  Is there some way to make the flow wait until the spreadsheet has the updated row, or to get the data directly from the form response?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I just added the tag excerpt to [tag:power-automate]. Please let me know if you have suggestions for the body of  tag wiki, need help to learn the ropes of this site or have anything that you would like to share about the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use **Get a row**, this isn't updated at the time that the response is submitted, instead use **Get Response Details**, from the same form, and the **Response Id**,

This will return the fields in the response which can then be tested, filtered and an email sent.

[image]